# How to automate the process of organizing audio files on Windows

Tags: windows, file-management, mp3

My library is a mess and manually organizing it in Windows Explorer is painful.

I know MediaMonkey Gold provides tools to automatically organize your library folders, however are there any open-source or free tools that can also organize files automatically?

Here is what I would like to accomplish:

I currently have a single folder with all of my music files inside it. I want to organize the files like this:

```
c:\music\<file_format>\<artist_name>\<album_name>

e.g.
C:\music\mp3\artist\album
C:\music\vob\artist\album
etc.
```

Comment: Why do you don't want to use MediaMonkey?

Comment: Curious, what features versus the free version of Media Monkey were you targeting? It would help a ton if you were more **specific** on what features you are looking for, how your files are currently organized and formatted, and what the ideal final result would be. Do you want them tagged, folders, or maybe in just one huge folder with long file names?? Your question in its current format is far too vague and risks being closed for the same reasons.

Comment: Search based on artist name, or genera...

Comment: I would need to purchase Media Monkey Gold to get the file organization feature.  I was looking at free options before I spend any money.  I also added an example of what I am looking for in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) along with the context operation `File Operations > Move To`.

Here is a [link to a wiki article](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:File_operations) with all the details.

Hope that helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iTunes, for all it's faults and bloat, has been my favorite for organizing my music. If you really don't like the program, use it at least to set up the structure and put the songs in place, and then remove it and use a different tool for the playing of the music.

Answer (score 0):

[mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) will do this, assuming you want a music player agnostic solution. Assuming everything is tagged properly, something like `c:\music\%_codec%\%artist%\%album%\%title%` in the "tag to filename" option under "convert" will do the trick.

mp3tag should be able to automate nearly *any* music file management, assuming you take the time to learn it

Answer (score 0):

I've found J. River Media Center to very capable of such things. As with some of the others mentioned here, you'll have to spend a bit of time learning it. There's a very active forum that provides good help with that. With an expression language that includes regular expressions, its advanced capabilities are definitely pitched at techies.  It is a commercial product, but there's a free, fully-functional trial version that works for 30 days.